# How to Inject ExecutionContext or format property and use it on My FieldExtractor with SpringBatch

Tags: batch-processing, spring-batch

I had to implement a customized FieldExtractor for my job like:

```
public class MyFieldExtractor implements
    FieldExtractor<MyEntity> {

    @Override
    public Object[] extract(MyEntity e) {
           ......
    }
}
```

In my xml, I use it in my customized Line Aggregator, like:
The "format" property is bind dynamically.

```
<bean id="myLineAggregator"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator" scope="step">
    <property name="fieldExtractor">
        <bean
            class=".........MyFieldExtractor">
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="format" value="1$01d%#{jobExecutionContext[$jc{filename}].dynamicFormat}"/>
</bean> 

I need a way to inject or to get the "format" property in my class MyFieldExtractor or at least, I would to inject the ExecutionContext in some field.
```

I tried:

```
@Value("#{jobExecutionContext[]}")
private ExecutionContext context;

@Value("#{jobExecutionContext}")
private ExecutionContext context;
```

unsuccessfully...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`JobExecution`s (as well as `StepExecution`s) are not directly bindable so `@Value("#{jobExecutionContext}")` doesn't work.
You can inject `1$01d%#{jobExecutionContext[$jc{filename}].dynamicFormat}` or `#{jobExecutionContext[$jc{filename}]}` using `@Value()` annotation.

Comment: I try this, but I receive an error: PROD  Descricao de saida: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.myLineAggregator' defined in class path resource [..../write-layer.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'MyFieldExtractor#18ab1e1c' of type [MyFieldExtractor] while setting bean property 'fieldExtractor';

Comment: post full stack trace, probably you need to proxy-target-class=true (or use interfaces for properties where possible instead of concrete classes)